# How to properly poweroff external HDD in HDD rack

Tags: debian, hard-disk, power-management, external-hdd

I got Pi4 4Gb running rasbian (similar to Debian) and Orico 4bay HDD rack connected with USB3.

Earlier with same host and one HDD in separate enclosure I was able to power off disk using:

```
sudo udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sda
```

But now, for this four disks enclosure rack I got errors like this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
└─sda1        8:1    0 931.5G  0 part  
  └─md0       9:0    0 931.4G  0 raid1 /mnt/raid
sdb           8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk  
└─sdb1        8:17   0 931.5G  0 part  
  └─md0       9:0    0 931.4G  0 raid1 /mnt/raid
sdc           8:32   0   2.7T  0 disk  
└─sdc1        8:33   0   2.7T  0 part  /mnt/wdred
sdd           8:48   0   1.8T  0 disk  
└─sdd1        8:49   0   1.8T  0 part  
mmcblk0     179:0    0  14.8G  0 disk  
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   256M  0 part  /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0  14.6G  0 part  /
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo umount /mnt/raid 
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo umount /mnt/wdred 
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdc
Error powering off drive: Error opening /dev/sdb for fsync: Device or resource busy (udisks-error-quark, 0)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sda
Error powering off drive: Error opening /dev/sdb for fsync: Device or resource busy (udisks-error-quark, 0)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdb
Error powering off drive: Error opening /dev/sdb for fsync: Device or resource busy (udisks-error-quark, 0)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdd
Error powering off drive: Error opening /dev/sdb for fsync: Device or resource busy (udisks-error-quark, 0)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

If I shutdown pi and the turn off this rack with power button on it I see increment of Power-Off_Retract_Count attribute in HDD Smart (so this is not graceful power off, but emergency retract).

How can I properly power off drives in this rack?

Comment: `Device or resource busy` is the problem.  Something(s) are using the drives.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43413/how-can-i-safely-remove-a-sata-disk-from-a-running-system (from comments in the accepted answer, step 5 is more useful than step 4 and step 4 should not be done). You'll have to do something about MD raid (since this answer covers only DM raid).

Answer (score 1):

After the `umount` commands, you should do a

```
sudo mdadm --misc --stop /dev/md0
```

and make sure it's successfully completed before trying to power off drives.

Since you are getting "device or resource busy" errors on all four disks (even from the non-RAID `sdc` and unmounted `sdd`, the next step would be to ensure you don't have any disk monitoring software (e.g. `smartd`) running, and stop them first if you do.

You might also want to use `sudo fuser -v /dev/sd*` to see if any processes are still using the disks before trying to power them off.

Comment: Sir you are absolutely right - I completely forgot to stop madam array